# Try to run Vaadin app on local, it's up but login screen displays a blank page

Tags: authentication, vaadin

```
2023-08-16 15:10:14.710  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework   : HttpSession supported: true
2023-08-16 15:10:14.710  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework   : Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
2023-08-16 15:10:14.710  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework   : Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: Apache Tomcat/9.0.53 using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
2023-08-16 15:10:14.710  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework   : Atmosphere Framework 2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1 started.
2023-08-16 15:10:14.724  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework   : Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
2023-08-16 15:10:15.075  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8180 (https) with context path ''
2023-08-16 15:10:16.226  INFO 11516 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.moduleui.ModuleUiApplication   : Started ModuleUiApplication in 15.435 seconds (JVM running for 19.901)
2023-08-16 15:10:17.727  INFO 11516 --- [)-172.27.27.139] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-08-16 15:10:17.727  INFO 11516 --- [)-172.27.27.139] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-08-16 15:10:17.729  INFO 11516 --- [)-172.27.27.139] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

But `localhost:8010/login` is a blank page. It only seems to happen on my PC, as it's working on my colleague's local.

Comment: Why do you expect the problem to be related to those INFO level logging?
Have you compared it with your colleague and did they differ? How? What
does your browsers dev console tell you about the blank page?

Comment: "Tomcat started on port(s): 8180 (https) with context path '' does not sound port 8010 to me, did you try to open it using " localhost:8180/login"?

Comment: GET https://localhost:8180/VAADIN/static/client/client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: The client there is either not compiled (you have your own widgetset) or you have not included a pre compiled one. What is needed and how to do it, depends on your setup. Hints are here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/addons/addons-maven#addons.maven.compiling

Comment: I don't have my own widgetset, how to include compiled one with gradle in intellij?