# vaadin 8 get https://localhost:8180/VAADIN/static/client/client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js not found

Tags: vaadin

my Vaadin 8 program starts without problems and all sources are build (e.g. generated-flow-imports.js). I got no java compile error or runtime error. BUT i only see a blank page in browser and the console shows following error:

https://localhost:8180/VAADIN/static/client/client-4C23589935A74206212F474A719FC41C.cache.js not found. https://locahost:8180/login shows blank page

The program runs on a Tomcat 9. Did someone have the same problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify which version you're using. If `generated-flow-imports.js` is created, then you're not using Vaadin 8 since that feature was introduced in Vaadin 14.

Comment: This could be, if you did not deploy the correct widgetset, or some caching somewhere exists

Comment: vaadin 8. sorry. it's not generated-flow-imports.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [try to run vaadin app on local, it's up but login screen is blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916454/try-to-run-vaadin-app-on-local-its-up-but-login-screen-is-blank-page)